# woocommerce emails notifications not working

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

I am not receiving order notification emails or user registration emails for woocommerce.

I am using latest woocommmerce plugin version 2.6.1 and have enabled all the emails alerts in the Woocommerce email settings.

Below is the screenshot from my woocommerce email settings. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: not sure why it is down voted while being a genuine question.

Answer (score 0):

What is your sender email?

Make sure your "From email:" ends with **@yourdomain.com**. That's a common issue with Wordpress and sending emails.

Comment: Yes "From email:" was given as `no-reply@yourdomain.com`. But it doesn't work

Answer (score -2):

I had the same probleme. All mails beside "new order" email and "processing" email where not sending. I waste about a week searching for a fix. In my case the problem was php version. In Woocommerce => Sistem Status you cand find a hint about the version you should use :).